# How to remove `/index` from URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the code below in .htaccess to remove .html from the end of file names, but the problem I'm facing is when I go to index.html it is appending the url `/index`, which I don't want.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to avoid duplicate content, you should redirect every url with `XXXX.html` to `XXXX`.
Then, add a redirection from `/index` to `/`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L,QSA]
```